# Ruby: Allocate another memory for included module variables

Tags: ruby

I have a simple module and 3 classes:

```
module InitSubclass
    @@subclass_instances = []

    def initialize
        super
        @@subclass_instances << self
    end

    def self.instances?
        @@subclass_instances
    end
end

class Animal
    attr_reader :type
    @@animal_instances = []

    def self.instances?
        @@animal_instances
    end

    def initialize
        @type = self.class
        @@animal_instances << self
        puts "A new #{self} has been instantiated."
    end

end

class Cow < Animal
    include InitSubclass
end

class Dog < Animal
    include InitSubclass
end
```

Now i run:

```
cow = Cow.new
puts cow.type
dog1 = Dog.new
dog2 = Dog.new

puts Animal.instances?.inspect
puts Cow.instances?.inspect
puts Dog.instances?.inspect
```

And the output:

```
A new #<Cow:0x000000028520a8> has been instantiated.
Cow
A new #<Dog:0x00000002851f40> has been instantiated.
A new #<Dog:0x00000002851e78> has been instantiated.
[#<Cow:0x000000028520a8 @type=Cow>, #<Dog:0x00000002851f40 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x0
0000002851e78 @type=Dog>]
[#<Cow:0x000000028520a8 @type=Cow>, #<Dog:0x00000002851f40 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x0
0000002851e78 @type=Dog>]
[#<Cow:0x000000028520a8 @type=Cow>, #<Dog:0x00000002851f40 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x0
0000002851e78 @type=Dog>]
```

This means that it uses same @@subclass_instances variable. If i copy the code from module and duplicate in all my subclasses it works fine:

```
A new #<Cow:0x000000028520a8> has been instantiated.
Cow
A new #<Dog:0x00000002851f40> has been instantiated.
A new #<Dog:0x00000002851e78> has been instantiated.
[#<Cow:0x000000028520a8 @type=Cow>, #<Dog:0x00000002851f40 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x0
0000002851e78 @type=Dog>]
[#<Cow:0x000000028520a8 @type=Cow>]
[#<Dog:0x00000002851f40 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x00000002851e78 @type=Dog>]
```

How can i tell it to allocate another var for every include module ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your overall goal is just to track the instances of any and all animals, you can do that without the module.

```
class Animal
  attr_reader :type

  def self.instances
    @instances ||= []
  end

  def initialize
    @type = self.class
    self.class.instances << self
    self.class.superclass.instances << self
    puts "A new #{self} has been instantiated."
  end
end

class Cow < Animal
end

class Dog < Animal
end
```

when executed:

```
A new #<Cow:0x3c7bc48> has been instantiated.
Cow
A new #<Dog:0x3c7bab0> has been instantiated.
A new #<Dog:0x3c7b9f0> has been instantiated.
Dog instances: 

[#<Cow:0x3c7bc48 @type=Cow>, #<Dog:0x3c7bab0 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x3c7b9f0 @type=Dog>]
[#<Cow:0x3c7bc48 @type=Cow>]
[#<Dog:0x3c7bab0 @type=Dog>, #<Dog:0x3c7b9f0 @type=Dog>]
```

It is also possible to get this functionality through a module. As with the last example, the goal is to set instance variables on the class itself (specifically on the [eigenclass](http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html) for the class). Also, because we need class methods and instance methods, we are using a little trick to include and extend.

```
module InitSubclass
  def self.included base
    base.extend InitEigenSubclass
  end

  def initialize
    super
    self.class.instance_variable_set(:@instances, (self.class.instance_variable_get(:@instances) || [])<< self)
  end

  module InitEigenSubclass
    def instances
      @instances
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It was more like an "include" problem ... How can i tell it to allocate another var for every include module ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, @RaduGabor, I was unsure of what you were trying to accomplish. I added in a solution using a module as well.